# Dojo build how to minify code written in ECMASCRIPT5?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, dojo, google-closure-compiler

I am using [dojo build tools](https://github.com/dojo/util) in order to minify my project.

Part of my code is written using `ECMASCRIPT5` and I receive and error from Closure Compiler when running the **standard** [.bat file](https://github.com/dojo/util/blob/master/buildscripts/build.bat).

It seems that they are some limitation as by default the compiler is set on ES3 as [described here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations).

---

```
0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
builderReference.js.uncompressed.js:15: ERROR - Parse error. getters are not supported in older versions of JS. If you are targeti
ng newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option.
        get builder() {
^
```

---

I need to be able to compile my ES5 code, and I change `.bat file` trying to pass the flag `language_in=ECMASCRIPT5`

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx256m  -cp "%~dp0../shrinksafe/js.jar";"%~dp0../closureCompiler/compiler.jar";"%~dp0../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  "%~dp0../../dojo/dojo.js" baseUrl="%~dp0../../dojo" load=build language_in=ECMASCRIPT5 %*
```

---

Unfortunately I still receive the same errors.

I would need to know:

- How to minify code written in ES5?
- Is the flag correct in the `.bat file`?
- Is it possible to add this configuration in xxx.profile.js?

Any ideas is very welcome thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following configuration in `app.profile.js` solve the issue.

```
// Set the optimization options for the Google closure compiler. 
optimizeOptions: { 
        languageIn: Packages.com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5 
}
```

From dojo documentation:

> optimizeOptions (default = "undefined") This object is passed to the
>   JavaScript optimizer to allow for compiler specific settings. Settings
>   for UglifyJS and closure compiler can be set using this object.

Unfortunately the docs does no provide the details for that object. Below some links with more resources:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Build-Pass-options-to-Closure-compiler-td4002152.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/qref.html

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/9f4sgewYnAw/G-oSqCz2DSEJ

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16196

https://github.com/dojo/util/pull/27

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Build-Pass-options-to-Closure-compiler-td4002152.html

https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16601